# Is an unbalanced categorical independent variable a problem for binomial logistic regression? (elaboration on a previous question)

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to predict the probability of an event to lead to a yes or no response. The independent variable is a categorical predictor with 3 levels.

I tested 21 infants; their responses to 3 different types of events (3 levels of the independent variable) were analyzed as a binary variable (yes/no). Infants contributed different amounts of data points for each level (e.g. 10, 12, 6), which eventually led to an unbalanced sample when looking at all the events contributed by all 21 infants in each of the 3 levels of the independent variable (i.e. 311, 180, 238). I'm interested in predicting the likelihood of each event to lead to a yes/no response.
**My first question is:** is it okay to have an unbalanced categorical independent variable in a binomial regression? (I'm not asking about unequal yes/no answers within each level, but about the total number of events in each level)
**My second question is:** how do I account for the fact that my participants contributed a different amount of data in each type of event? and is it okay to ignore subject variance? is it more appropriate to fit a different model here?

Comment: Your first question was already answered in your first question & as it stands, this seems to be a duplicate. This question might be distinct if you can elaborate on what you want to know specifically. What does it mean to "account for" the different numbers in each category? What problem are you worried about? What is the purpose of the logistic regression model & what problem does it solve?

Comment: The big question I have from your other question (which you should link in this question) is if you obtain your points by measuring the same infant several times.

Comment: yes, I do measure the same infant several times, hence the amount of data points -- each infant contributes multiple data points at each of the 3 levels, but those vary in number within and between infants due to data loss throughout the experiment.